# How to accomplish this task faster writing code with some hacks?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, performance

I've large text file for testing purposes containing about 130 millions of words. To count the words in the file I  had written following code, which I call "plain solution".

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7

with open('v_i_m_utf8.txt') as infile:
    words=0
    for line in infile:
        wordslist = line.split()
        words += len(wordslist)
print(words)
```

Results that I have now:

```
tony@lenox:~$ time ./counting.py

 134721552

 real   0m29,391s

 user   0m28,907s

 sys    0m0,400s

 tony@lenox:~$
```

So please, is it possible to use some python internals hacks and tricks to make it treat strings much faster?

I need just count the words and do it as fast as Python runtime can.

Comment: Rather than using python, did you try `wc -w v_i_m_utf8.txt`?  It is a mature purpose-written program, probably in C.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm intresting searching the solution in Python only for this case, without standart unix utils

Comment: @cdarke execution time on my hardware
`tony@lenox:~$ time wc -w v_i_m_utf8.txt


134721552 v_i_m_utf8.txt


real 0m55,585s

user 0m54,192s

sys 0m0,552s`

Comment: @cdarke, $ time wc -w v_i_m.utf 134721552 v_i_m.utf wc -w v_i_m.utf 33.26s user 0.18s system 99% cpu 33.461 total From PC with better perfomance that mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does Cython count?

```
cdef extern from "ctype.h":
    int isspace(int x)

def cfunc(fd):
  cdef bytes buf
  cdef int tot = 0, prev = 0, cur
  cdef char c
  while True:
      buf = fd.read(8192)
      if not buf:
        return tot
      for c in buf:
        cur = isspace(c)
        if cur and not prev:
          tot += 1
        prev = cur
```

The timings on my computer are:

- OP's example takes 6.5s
- George's takes 5.3s
- This Cython code takes 0.65s
- A similar C version takes 0.73s (not sure why longer than Cython)

  compiled with `gcc -mtune=native -march=native -Wall -O3`

Comment: Yes it is cout of course. 

Give me full listing of your program to compile it with Cython, please.

Comment: but I appreciate your help, show me please short example of usage of your solution anyway

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python3

    from cfunc import cfunc
 
    with open('v_i_m_utf8.txt', 'rb') as infile:
       words = 0
       words = cfunc(infile)    

print(words)`


I guess that is correct.

Comment: I tend to play in a Jupyter notebook which has nice support for Cython…  your example is about right, no need to initialise `words=0` as you're immediately setting it to something else, but you've basically got it

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole file instead of going line by line.

```
words = len(infile.read().split())
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but that example dies, killed by OOM killer, while running on my Lenovo G580 (Intel Core i3 2370M with 8Gb RAM) :-( 
Size of file is about 1.6Gb of the utf8 encoded Russian text.
My code from the OP eats this amount of data without any problems with memory consumption...

Comment: You can pass an argument to `read` to limit the number of bytes read. Read and process chunks until the file is done and sum the lengths like in your original.